# scipy PchipInterpolator Error: 'array cannot be safely cast to required type'

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, type-conversion

I would like to do some piecewise cubic hermite interpoaltion on some input data from pyaudio:

```
#input comes as string and is converted to int16
numpyData = numpy.fromstring(inData, dtype=numpy.int16)

#x positions of my y data
x = numpy.arange(len(numpyData))

#as i always want to interpolate to 4096 these are my indices
interpolationIndices = numpy.linspace(0, len(numpyData), num=4096, endpoint=False)

#my interpolator and print for testing
f = interpolate.PchipInterpolator(x, numpyData)
print f(interpolationIndices[0])
```

The error log now says:

```
TypeError: array cannot be safely cast to required type
```

The doc for scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator says it should be an array of real values but as im aware int16 should be real enough and my x-pos array is is sorted monotonic as well.

**Additional Information:**

```
print numpyData
```

results in:

```
[3153 2362 5361 ..., 3206 -849 3241]
```

so all integer values as expected.

Full trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "/Users/myUser/Documents/workspace/myProject/AudioController.py", line 9, in callback  
return self.file.getAudio(frame_count, scaleMethod()), pyaudio.paContinue  
File "/Users/myUser/Documents/workspace/myProject/NewFileHandler.py", line 34, in getAudio
    data = self.resample(data)  
File "/Users/myUser/Documents/workspace/myProject/NewFileHandler.py", line 168, in resample
    f = interpolate.PchipInterpolator(x, numpyData)  
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/polyint.py", line 932, in __init__
    data[:,1] = PchipInterpolator._find_derivatives(xp, yp)  
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/polyint.py", line 982, in _find_derivatives
    PchipInterpolator._edge_case(mk[0],dk[1], dk[0])  
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/scipy/interpolate/polyint.py", line 947, in _edge_case
    out[mask] = 1.0/(1.0/m0[mask]+1.0/d1[mask])  
TypeError: array cannot be safely cast to required type
```

numpyData.dtype:

```
int16
```

numpy version:

```
print numpy.__version__
1.6.2
```

scipy version:

```
print scipy.__version__
0.13.2
```

Comment: @alko additional info added above. pyaudio packs int16 data into strings which is converted via numpy to usable data. As the numpyData is plain int16 i was thinking this shouldn't cause the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definetely a bug (see bottom), and is reproducible in numpy 1.6.2 with following setup:

```
import scipy.interpolate
import numpy as np
y = np.array([0,1,2], dtype=np.int16)
x = np.arange(len(y))
```

Then exception is raised with:

```
>>> np.__version__
1.6.2
# code skipped
>>> scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator(x, y)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
    out[mask] = 1.0/(1.0/m0[mask]+1.0/d1[mask])
TypeError: array cannot be safely cast to required type
```

While works as expected for numpy 1.8.0:

```
>>> np.__version__
1.8.0
# code skipped
>>> scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator(x, y)
<scipy.interpolate.polyint.PchipInterpolator object at 0x044371F0>
```

Your option is probably to upgrade numpy.

P.s. it's a boolean indexing bug, didn't find in tracker, following is a short example to reproduce:

```
out = np.array([0])
out[np.array([True])] = np.array([.5])
```

Comment: upgrading numpy solved it. sadly the interpolator is so amazingly slow that i have to find another way... thanks!

Comment: @MaximilianKörner feel free to come up with your actual task and sampel code, to ask for a way to speed things up if needed